# IWICBitmapDecoder::Initialize() failing

Tags: c++, wic

I have a byte stream `pBitmap`, And i need to create a decoder from it. so I tried as follows

```
IWICStream *piStream = NULL;
IWICBitmapDecoder *piDecoder = NULL;

//piFactory is my IWICImagingFactory 
hr = piFactory->CreateStream(&piStream);

//lRawSize is bufferSize
//pBitmap is my byte buffer
hr = piStream ->InitializeFromMemory(pBitmap, lRawSize);

hr = piFactory->CreateDecoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg,NULL,&piDecoder);

//HERE i got the error. 
hr = piDecoder->Initialize(piStream, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand);
```

hr returns component not found. 
What could be the problem here.

**update**:

I was not sure whether the bitmap source im intend to decode is jpg or not. so i can understand that pass container format as "GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg" is not right. 
so i tried `IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream`

```
 hr = piFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream(
    piStream,
    NULL,
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,
    &piDecoder
    );
```

But the result was same. 
and i initiate the stream from a file. which isworked fine.

```
hr = piStream ->InitializeFromFilename(L"C..\\test.jpg",GENERIC_READ);
```

So the problem should be in the initiating the stream.

I created a encoder and do some stuf and save them in to a file using `writepixel`(without creating a decoder)

```
hr = piBitmapFrame->WritePixels(
    lHeight, 
    cbStride, 
    cbBufferSize, 
    pBitmap);
```

and it saves a fine image. so icould say that pBitmap surely contains image data.

What could be the problem here.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the image you're decoding is a JPEG?

Comment: Also, you may want to consider [IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690309(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Hawkmooon. actually I dont.! that could be the reason. thankyou. But then i tried CreateDecoderFromStream and it fails too.

Comment: Have you solved it? I just found today that I can decode any image except the JPEG... and it is quite old MS issue -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a53282ef-bb64-4c6e-918a-115492ac32b5/no-automatic-wic-decoder-for-jpg-files?forum=windowswic

Comment: I just found, that JPEG decoder needs set the stream to head (which is not required with other decoders) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928336/494472

Answer (score 0):

The cause of an error is in using pointers to different objects. `piStreamTemp` was initialized from bitmap array, but `piDecoder` Initialized using `piStream` which is empty and was not properly initialized.

In addition, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ee719792(v=vs.85).aspx) is a recommendation to avoid using method InitializeFromMemory and workaround for this has described.